# ASP.NET @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I use @Html.EditoFor for a password input like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
```

I want to make it like this

```
<input type="password">
```

to be hide what I am typing with stars

Can Anyone Help me?

Comment: Why not use PasswordFor ?

Comment: EditorFor relies (in part) on your model being properly annotated. Do you have a `[DataType(DataType.Password)] attribute on that property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `EditorFor` use `PasswordFor` like this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
```